# How can i know the function is convex or not?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

As an examples i am sending you following two functions $f1(x)$, and $f2(x)$ to find either functions are convex or not?[image]

These are well-known functions used in robust estimation.My question is how to check the function is convex or not. I have learned in from literature that convex always has unique local solution.Is it true?

Thanks

Comment: 1. Why is there so much white space in your image? 2. Do you know the definition of a convex function?

Answer (score 4):

One way to check convexity for a function $f(x)$ is to see if its double derivative is always positive. Consider the second function $f_2(x)$.

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{df_2(x)}{dx} & = \dfrac{2x(1+x^2) - 2x^3}{2(1+x^2)^2} = \dfrac{x}{(1+x^2)^2}\\
\dfrac{d^2f_2(x)}{dx^2}& = \dfrac{(1+x^2)^2 - 4x^2(1+x^2)}{(1+x^2)^4} = \dfrac{(1+x^2)(1-3x^2)}{(1+x^2)^4}.
\end{align*}

Since the second derivative can be negative, $f_2(x)$ is not convex. Similarly you can work with $f_1(x)$.

Comment: f1(x) is a piece of cake to evaluate. I'd say the odds of it being convex are pretty fair :) I leave it to the OP to verify.  @Greenparker, your derivative formulas have a typo in which you write $f_1$ rather than $f_2$.

Comment: This check isn't sufficiently thorough.  Because $f_1$ is not differentiable at the origin, you need to conduct a separate check there: it is not enough to verify that the second derivative is positive only where it can be computed!

Comment: Thank you very much for all of you for giving your inputs according your understanding.